# How to limit DEX memory usage

Tags: android, gradle, dex

I am trying to set the maximum memory that DEX task can use in a gradle-based Android project, but can't find any option to do that.

My motivation to do this is because as `dex` sometimes takes so much memory that my computer starts swapping and becomes completely unresponsive for some minutes (so I would rather see the task fail and then free some more resources and retry)

In my `gradle.properties` I have `org.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx300m"` which limits the memory used by Gradle itself, but when Gradle starts dx it always uses `-Xmx1024`.

So how can I make Gradle limit the memory used by dx?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your build.gradle script, set the dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize configuration to whatever value you need:

```
android {
//snip
//add this into your existing 'android' block
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
//snip
}
```

[Source](http://metova.com/tech/blog/2014/08/27/overhead-limit-exceeded/)