# com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google sign in, in my app, I added these libraries:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
```

Also add this to project build gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'
```

Also add plugin to app build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

then add required permissions
but when I try to run my app, received this error:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Try adding `multiDexEnabled true` to your app **build.gradle** file.

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**EDIT:**

Try Steve's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32826010/4671754) first. In case it happens frequently or first step didn't help `multiDexEnabled` might help. For those who love to dig deeper here is couple similar issues (with more answers):

[:app:dexDebug ExecException finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30001051/2146871)

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28917696/2146871)

Comment: Did not work for me.  Steve's answer - Cleaning did the trick.  I just upgraded to AS1.5 Preview

Comment: To be fair you should always check whether an issue can be solved by cleaning. I am convinced this will help to those to whom cleaning did not do the trick.

Comment: both of these didnt help for me - but restarting AS finally did the trick :)

Comment: non of these helped me, but it started to work after I restarted AS

Comment: I would also advise checking out A Grandt's answer, below ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/33690032/1617737 ) before you jump in with this solution.

Comment: Note, if you are using cordova or ionic to clean you run `projectdirectory/platforms/android/cordova/clean`

Answer (score 146):

Another thing to watch for, is that you don't use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

That will import ALL the play services, and it'll only take little more than a hello world to exceed the 65535 method limit of a single dex APK.

Always specify only the services you need, for instance:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
```

Comment: You are the best! This solved my problem. Rebuilding doesn't help in my case as mentioned in many of the solutions. As you mentioned the Google Play Services library has [a lot of subcomponents](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) and they should be imported just as you've said - one by one.

Many thanks, again!

Comment: I had this issue in the last couple of days.  I thought I had only picked what I need.  But, low and behold, after hours of looking I was importing all of play-services when all I wanted was play-services-ads.  Definitely check your gradle dependencies people!

Comment: @A.Grandt could you add the [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) Ivan has given into your answer? It contains a list of names of all subcomponents and it should be part of the answer, because it's the next step everyone has to take.

Answer (score 136):

I just had to Clean my project and then it built successfully afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! It works flawlessly! The accepted answer would be weird as my project is far from reaching 65K method limit (which would need multidex).

Comment: Yep, cleaning was the way to go. AS 1.4

Comment: If you have library modules then clean all the modules across the project to have it working. Cleaning only individual modules didnt work for me. Clean the ENTIRE project.

Comment: Can someone tell me how do I clean the project? I've been trying lot of "combinations" and nothing works.  I see everybody says "clean", but don't know how. Thx.

Comment: @AlbertoRubio, under Build > Clean Project in AS toolbar.

Comment: Didn't work me. Cleaning would be the first thing anyone tries anyway.

Comment: the exception comes while running the app. Build is successful while cleaning or rebuild.

Answer (score 23):

This error began appearing for me when I added some new methods to my project. I knew that I was nowhere near the 65k method limit and did not want to enable multiDex support for my project if I could help it.

I resolved it by increasing the memory available to the `:app:transformClassesForDexForDebug` task. I did this by specifying **javaMaxHeapSize** in `gradle.build`.

**gradle.build**

```
android {
    ...
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
    }
}
```

I tried this after having had no success with other common solutions to this problem:

- Running a project `clean`
- Manually deleting the `/app/build` and `/build` directories from my project
- Invalidating Gradle Cache and restarting Android Studio

**Error**

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   > ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1

Note: increasing the memory available to the DEX task can cause performance problems on systems with lower memory - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378413/how-to-limit-dex-memory-usage).

Comment: This worked for me, just to specify the maximum heap size will solve the issue, thank you Maurice

Answer (score 8):

I also faced similar issue in Android Studio 1.5.1 and gradle 1.5.0.
I just have to remove unwanted libraries from dependencies which may be automatically added in my app's build.gradle file.
One was :  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'.
So for best practices try to only include specific play services library like for ads include only

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

Although

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

this will also solve the issue, but provides with a lot of Notes in gradle console, making it confusing to find the other real issues during build

Comment: Narrowing my google api usage to just play-services-maps did the trick.  Here is Google's official breakdown of the various components in the play-services API: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Answer (score 4):

you can see the documentation of [Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using AS 1.5.1 and encountered the same problem. But just cleaning the project just wont do, so I tried something.

- clean project
- restart AS
- Sync Project

This worked with me, so I hope this helps.

Comment: This would be pointless for projects which have exceeded the 64k Dex method limit.

Answer (score 3):

At my case change buildToolsVersion from "24" to "23.0.2", solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the Exception occurred because all google play service extensions are not with same version as follows

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.8.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.8.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
```

It worked when I changed this to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.8.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.8.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
```

Comment: I didn't browse to all the answers and I didn't see yours, so ... I discovered that *this* was my case about an hour later :/

Answer (score 2):

#### I resolved it with the next:

I configured
  [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=es-419)

In build.gradle you need to add the next one.

```
android {
...
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       // Enabling multidex support.
       multiDexEnabled true
       ...
   }
   dexOptions {
      incremental true
      maxProcessCount 4 // this is the default value
      javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
   }
...
}
dependencies {
...
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
...
}
```

Add the next one in local.properties

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

After that into Application class you need to add the Multidex too.

```
 public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       //mas codigo
   }

   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(base);
       MultiDex.install(this);
   }
}
```

Don't forget add the line code into Manifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
/>
```

That's it with this was enough for resolve the bug:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug. 

Check very well into build.gradle with javaMaxHeapSize "2g" and the local.properties org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m are of 2 gigabyte.

Comment: Please post in English only. This looks like a good answer, it'd be a shame for it to be deleted because it's not in English.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem when i rolled back to old version via git, and that version had previous .jar library of one 3rd party api, and for some reason turned out that both jar of the same sdk, just different versions were in /libs folder.

Answer (score 1):

First Delete intermediates files
  YOUR APP FOLDER\app\build\intermediates
OR
  Clean your project and then rebuild.

Thent add

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

i.e.

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

It's work for me

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by change to use latest `buildToolsVersion`

```
android {
    //...
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2' // change from '23.0.2'
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A helpful answer if all above didn't work for you.

Go to your app gradle file,

***Check all the dependency versions are mentioned with proper version code*** rather than any relative value like (com.example.demo:+)

Previous - implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'

After - implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.30.0'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest gradle version ie  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' and  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'`, then try updating the latest support respository from the SDK manager and rebuild the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

If you need add this reference for cordova plugin add next line in your plugin.xml file.

```
<framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:+" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the different dependencies have a same jar also cause this build error.

For example:

```
compile('com.a.b:library1');
compile('com.c.d:library2');
```

If "library1" and "library2" has a same jar named `xxx.jar`, this will make such an error.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me because of Eclipse memory leak. I had to restart my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a couple of pngs and the build number in the gradle and now I get this.  No amount of cleaning and restarting helped.  Disabling Instant Run fixed it for me.  YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I had the same option and as soon as I turned off Instant run, it worked fine on my API16 device, but on the API24 device it worked fine with Instant run.

Hope this helps someone having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to Build - Edit Build Types - Properties Tab - Build Type Version and downgrade it to ver 23.0.1. Click ok.
This works for android studio 1.5.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

the write answer is in **gradle** put
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
}
then **application name in manifest** 
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
wish this answer is hellpful to some one

Answer (score 0):

this code solved problem

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

For easiest way to implement google sign in visit: **[google sign in android](http://demonuts.com/2017/02/07/google-plus-sign-in-integration-in-android-studio/)**

Also try

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
    }
```

Also keep same version number for different services.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding:
In `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

in `local.properties` ,

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

mention dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Clean and Rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Incase 'Instant Run' is enable, then just disable it.