# Gradle build error, Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I've updated the Android studio for 1.4, also gradle version updated(1.4.0-beta3).

It is my build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //ViewPagerIndicator
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://devrepo.kakao.com:8088/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
    }
}
```

And this is the build result.

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2221Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk410Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGithubLawloretienneQuickreturn001Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGithubRey5137Material121Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComKakaoSdkAuth112Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComKakaoSdkKakaolink112Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComKakaoSdkKakaostory112Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComKakaoSdkKakaotalk112Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComKakaoSdkUsermgmt112Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComKakaoSdkUtil112Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComViewpagerindicatorLibrary241Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComWefikaFlowlayout030Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview130Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidexInstrumentation101Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithExtractJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug FAILED
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>
> > java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Develop\workspace\b2c\Apps\app-meterial\app\build\intermediates\transforms\RESOURCES\FULL_PROJECT\mergeJavaRes\debug\META-INF\license\LICENSE.base64.txt
> >     (지정된 경로를 찾을 수 없습니다)
>
> Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 5.62 secs
>   Information:1 error Information:0 warnings Information:See complete
>   output in console

What is the problem?
Thank you for your attention, I'll be looking forward to hearing from you!

Best Regards.

Comment: Show your console data

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I have no idea what is causing it.

Comment: I had solve. just replace [classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta3'] to [classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3']  in my  build.gradle file.  but, I would like to know the different solutions.

Comment: Jiho's method works for me too. Thanks

Comment: you do not have to use the *old* 1.2.3, 1.3.1 also works :) always use the lastest stable (from http://mvnrepository.com/)

Answer (score 28):

Try adding multiDexEnabled true to your app build.gradle file.

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

I did not try but It marked as answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811133)

Comment: Even if this did work, this isn't the only step to enabling Multidex

Answer (score 23):

This is what worked for me, added it into build.gradle:

```
android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        }
    }
```

Comment: any implication on the project when i use that?

Comment: Late, but your answer worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

i had solve this issue,just add

```
packagingOptions{
   //  this is my setting:
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
  //  you should 
    exclude 'META-INF/license\LICENSE.base64.txt'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to fix my problem by using **packagingOptions** into my build.grade under "app" folder. into that packagingOptions folder I did the following:

I **EXCLUDED** the message that was appearing on my grade.console whenever the project was failing.

For instance: if when your gradle console fails it says it could not execute because of META-INF/XXX so what you can do is

```
android { 

  packagingOptions  {

        exclude 'META-INF/XXX'
 }
```

Add it to the build.gradle under "app" folder.

Answer (score 1):

I used this combination

```
           buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

and

```
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

with

```
compileSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 22
```

and

```
   defaultConfig {   multiDexEnabled true}
```

And now my code compile for classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta3'
I try Vector graphics

Answer (score 1):

After all answer tried can't work anyone, only work after invalid caches/restart press it work.
mention that: Above answer that i include don't remove from my project.

```
 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'

    }
 multiDexEnabled true
```

so that would be a answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

perform `./gradlew clean` in your root project after adding

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with some assets. In my case I had to downgrade the Gradle version to 1.2.3 and it worked again.

Excluding those files in my first attempt well...excluded the files from my app which didn´t make the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Update your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:VERSION'**  Look for your build tools update
}
```

Path:
**/platforms/android/build.gradle**

for other versions: go to android website
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-plugin

Answer (score 0):

The error might be because of an Android X requirement. Make sure to migrate project to Android X. You can do this through Android studio.

[Follow the procedures here to Migrate your Project to Android X](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration)

Answer (score -1):

Try doing: 
Invalidate caches and Restart.

It worked in my case.