# Exception failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have an .aar file in my app module libs folder and then I Synchronize with Android in android studio it builds SUCCESSFULL, but if I try to BUILD APK then it shows following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Exception failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 3028547021 but got 599 bytes)

Exception detail

> Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 3018547021 but got 599 bytes)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JarMerger.addJar(JarMerger.java:147)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MergeJavaResourcesTransform.copyIntoJar(MergeJavaResourcesTransform.java:464)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MergeJavaResourcesTransform.transform(MergeJavaResourcesTransform.java:335)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:151)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:148)
>           at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)

I have applied tricks given on different answers in stackoverflow but non be helpful.

My gradle file looks like this:

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
    // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
    // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
    exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    //exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license'
    //  exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}



buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}
dependencies {
compile(name: 'mycomponent-release', ext: 'aar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

}

I have applied following tricks from stackoverflow: 
[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031395/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformresourceswithmergejavaresfordebug)
[Gradle build error, Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901401/gradle-build-error-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformresourceswith)

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you've tried to solve the problem. Also, check that those questions also fail at `app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug` before attempting their solutions

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have put exclude in packageOptions in build.gradle file and also added  buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }

Comment: Those linked questions explicitly had error messages about the META-INF folder. Yours, on the other hand, seems to point out that the AAR project that you've included is much smaller than expected

Comment: I have added details about exception

Comment: Hava you manage to solve this?

Comment: The .aar file I was using, was corrupted. And I found few files which are duplicate in project. To check corrupted .aar file, try to extract it by calling "jar -xvf <aar file path>". If it extracts successfully then your file is not corrupted.