# Error in Android Studio when running my application

Tags: java, android

I am trying to work on new app on android studio, i used to work on e

> ```
>  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,          
>   0xffff]: 65536
> at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:484)
> at    com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:261)
>    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>  com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
> ```

What could this error be?

i have moved some jar files to my eclipse. and my build.gradle is like this

> ```
>    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>      android {
> compileSdkVersion 23
> buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
> defaultConfig {
>     applicationId "com.netvariant.heinz"
>     minSdkVersion 14
>     targetSdkVersion 21
>     versionCode 1
>     versionName "1.0"
> }
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         minifyEnabled false
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
>     }
> }}dependencies {
> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
> compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'}
> ```

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception

Answer (score 30):

I think your dex file is reached to its maximum method count. Try to use

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

in your deafault config or try to minmize your playservices from your dependencies. Use only required packages. Try changing your version or exclude unwanted packages