# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

Tags: java, android, android-webview

For some reason when i run the app in Android studio its giving me this:

```
Error:Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
Error:A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

This happnes in android studio. Here is my app:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.amanuel.webview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private WebView webView;
    private EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickEvent();
    }

    public void OnClickEvent(){
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Url_Button);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edit_Text_Url);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = editText.getText().toString();
                webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.amanuel.webview.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="URL"
        android:id="@+id/Url_Button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Edit_Text_Url"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Edit_Text_Url"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Url_Button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="https://google.com" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.amanuel.webview" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception

Comment: @Amanuel Bogale see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be having multiple dex files with same signatures to fix this add this in your app level gradle file.

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This **ERROR** have **POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

**SOLUTION 1.**

If some conflicting drawable resources found then It give the same error. So you have to clean the Project and rebuild it.

**SOLUTION 2.**

Problem with RAM : So close the application which are not used. and free the Memory RAM.

**SOLUTION 3.**

**GC overhead (out of memory)** :

so add this in build.gradle file.

```
android {

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
    }

}
```