# android - error when use google-directioner lib

Tags: android

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

i got error when use this lib

```
   compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
```

what does that mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)

Comment: @AntonShkurenko how can i fix this?

Comment: You can try to read two answers from that link as your first attempt.

Comment: @AntonShkurenko thanks for the answer but still not work. raise another error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzrn.class

Comment: @AntonShkurenko i fix this. i just need to comment my //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0' but still dont know why

Comment: Google for the 65K methods problem