# gradle error in building compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'

Tags: java, android, firebase

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

what should i do?
i do not have multiple copies of firebase-client in libs. its only present in external library.

my dependencies:

```
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
```

Comment: That had happened to me once, where my project had a lot of external libraries and I had exceeded 64k limit. I enabled multidex, configured a proguard file and set minifyEnabled to true (for debug and release modes), then the problem was solved. Hope that solves your problem too.

Comment: try this dependencies   dependencies {
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
}

Comment: remove the + sign... rebuild your project

Comment: @ExceptionLover: this is my dependencies

Comment: pooja, i edit the answer and improve

Comment: pooja... try this..  defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the + sign and clean and rebuild your project or try this dependencies [and also check on stack overflow answer, com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811133/3678308)

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        //your application id here
        applicationId "yourapp.com.demoapps"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1' 
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
     compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0' 
     compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0' 
     compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
            }
```

Comment: gradle is building when i comment this                                                   compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'  but i want both parse and firebase

Comment: remove the + sign from try compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2' some time server is not working with + sign. so dependencies  is not working..

Comment: i removed all + signs. it still the same

Comment: thank u soooooooo much,. it helped me so much :D such a life saver.

Comment: Multidex is a bad workaround for the issue. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you included too many dependencies and exceeded the [multidex limit](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

This line...

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

If you read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), there is a note

> **Note**: If the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K limit, your app may fail to compile. You may be able to mitigate this problem when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them. For information on how to do this, see [Selectively compiling APIs into your executable](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split).

You have already included the Google Maps API, so do you need any more Google Services than that? If so, pick those services from the link at the end of that note and remove that line I mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

It may be external library is not included correctly or try to use alternative library.