# Android Studio 2.1 RC fail to run with instant run disable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

After disable instant run I cannot deploy my application to device. If instant run is enable every thing works fine.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForEnemDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
> >     Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;

Comment: seems like a bug in the version

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception

Answer (score 0):

Check your SDK Location, this happened with me also, what resolved it was, resetting my android sdk location...its a bug with studio, hope it helps....if this doesnot help do tell me...