# Android Studio 2.1 won't run my App

Tags: java, android

I've just updated my Android Studio version to the new 2.1.
The problem is **after** I've launched my AVD, and I try to **run** my App, it **crashes** giving me a list of **errors**:

1st:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
```

2nd:

```
Error:1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
```

3rd:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**EDIT:**

Going to the right-top corner all the way through "**Gradel**" panel > :app > Tasks > build > double clicking on ***clean*** solved my issue!

Comment: have you tried gradle clean?

Comment: You mean "Clean project"?

Comment: I mean this: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=aa03d01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this post might be useful to you:

[com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)

From the post:

First clean your project. Go to the right hand side "gradle" pane, look for the clean task and execute it. Many times I've had this problem and I could get it to work just by cleaning the project.

If it does not work, then set the multiDexEnabled property to true:

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Do it in your app's build.gradle.

I hope it helps!