# Build fails due to missing dx.jar

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-studio-2.1, dx

Whenever I try to build the project, it shows the following error,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'>  com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: dx.jar is missing
```

I have recently updated my sdk and after that uninstalled android studio unchecking the sdk and downloaded the IDE(just because I wanted to update studio) without sdk and made it to use the present sdk.

Please help! I am not finding any solution working yet.

Comment: have you tried Build -> Clean Project ?

Comment: Yeah @dionellorera

Comment: Update SDK Platform and Build Tools

Comment: There is no option for update, I already have the updated ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting sdk platform tools and build tools and reinstalling them worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Did you update your build.gradle as well?

sample:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24 // this is important
    buildToolsVersion "24" // this also

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.bamboomy.yarne"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24 // recommended
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0' // and don't forget this
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0' // and this
}
```

I'm not an expert but it seems that in the

```
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2
```

dir there is no dx.jar (only a dx.bat)

and beginning from 23.0.3 there seems to be a

```
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\lib
```

folder with a dx.jar present

Answer (score 1):

I have to copy dx.jar from `/build-tools/33.0.0/lib/dx.jar` to `/build-tools/34.0.0/lib/dx.jar` when I set buildToolsVersion to version 34.

Comment: In fact this worked, in my case i copied dx.jar from 30.0.3 to 33.0.2

Answer (score 0):

It's related to your `buildToolsVersion` config in `build.gradle`

Go to your SDK path and find the `build-tools` directory and search for `dx.jar` file. Each folder that has `dx.jar` file could be your `buildToolsVersion`.

If not exist any `dx.jar` use SdkManager to download one build-tools

Answer (score -1):

add this to your **build.gradle**

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

[check this asnwer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)

Comment: I think, link i have mentioned should work, have you tried answers from that link.@UrjaPawar

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the dex method limit, so this answer isn't applicable.

Comment: did you have checked all asnwers from above mentioned link in my answer ?@UrjaPawar