# How to remove Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' of android

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: enable multidex in your gradle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception

Answer (score 0):

If your using Android Studio 2.1.2 and buildtoolVersion as 24.0.0. Downgrade it to 23.0.X.

Comment: But in my case it has gone after removing  the play store library,But I need It so still finding the solution.