# Android + Wear - Not building the app after create a new project

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I just created a new android project for mobile + wear.
I'm using the latest android studio version (2.2.2).
When I try to compile this build error is happening:
I didn't code nothing, just built.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

When I create only mobile app (without wear) everything works fine!

What is going on? How to fix it? Android studio bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)

Comment: Have you tried an older version like v 2.2.1 a more stable version of android studio and see if the error still persists?

Comment: No... :(
Do you have an older version to answer?