# Error while building apk file

Tags: java, android, apk

Whenever i try to build my apk file it fails with following error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf;

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception ?

Comment: did you use this in your gradle  multiDexEnabled true

Comment: @Vadivel Hi, yes i did and still the same error

Comment: did your  app have Application class

Answer (score 1):

```
Just try this code:

  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
  multiDexEnabled true


public class MyApp extends Application {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MultiDex.install(this);

}
```

manifestfile:

```
    <application
    android:name="com.activity.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    ....
   <activity name...../>
   />//application
```

Answer (score 1):

It complains about duplicate package, com/google/android/gms/auth, you can try a gradle clean / clean project as a simple step. If this doesn't work it means that somewhere in the project dependencies you are including this package more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to build tab and choose clean project.
After clean project completed make rebuild project.
then run your project.

i hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

please add this code in build.gradle(module:app)

```
    afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of this.. it might works

1. Clean and rebuild the module or,
2. Invalidate / restart android studio or,
3. Check Gradle dependencies duplicate and clean the gradle at the right taskbar or,
4. add `multiDexEnabled true` in your gradle defaulConfig

Answer (score 0):

A duplicate in the build.gradle file was the issue. Firebaseui was causing the build error.