# java error after upgrading android-sdk version

Tags: java, android, gradle

I was updating our gradle app from Android SDK 23 to 24 (25 doesn't work either) and am getting the following error.

```
Execution failed for task  :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForGoogleRelease'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\android\jdk\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried building both 24 and 25, with every variant of the build tools I could find and they all produce this error. Most of the cases I saw online by this error were solved by building clean or adding multidex, which we already use.

I have also tried changing the java max heap size.

Any ideas on how to get through this, or figure out what is actually going on?

dependancy block as requested:

```
dependencies {
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // Google Support Services
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    //googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2' // (Updated Aug 19, 2016)
    googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2' // (Updated Aug 19, 2016)
    googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.2' // (Updated Aug 19, 2016)
    googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2' // (Updated Aug 19, 2016)
    googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.0.2' // (Updated Aug 19, 2016)
    //ad mob
    googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.0.2'
    googleCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'

    // For multidex support for devices <= V20
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    // Help Shift (Updated Dec 8, 2015)
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.helpshift:android-aar:4.2.0-support'

    // Facebook (Updated Jan 27, 2015)
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'

    // Crashalytics (Updated Jan 8, 2016)
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Fyber  (Updated Dec 3, 2015)
    // begin (Update Fyber May 20, 2016)
    compile 'com.fyber:fyber-sdk:8.5.1'
    provided 'com.fyber:fyber-annotations:1.2.0'
    provided 'com.fyber:fyber-annotations-compiler:1.3.0'

    // Fyber Ad Networks
    compile 'com.fyber.mediation:adcolony:2.3.6-r2@aar'
    compile 'com.fyber.mediation:flurry:6.4.0-r1@aar'
    compile 'com.fyber.mediation:vungle:4.0.2-r1@aar'
    compile 'com.fyber.mediation:unityads:2.0.2-r1@aar'
    compile 'com.fyber.mediation:chartboost:6.5.0-r1@aar'
    compile 'com.fyber.mediation:applovin:6.3.0-r1@aar'
    compile 'com.fyber.mediation:hyprmx:4.0.1-r3@aar'

    // end (Update Fyber May 20, 2016)
    compile(name:'fyber-facebook-4.11.0-r2', ext:'aar')

    // Vungle third-party dependencies  (Updated Dec 8, 2015)
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'


    // Kiip SDK  (Updated Dec 4, 2015)
    googleCompile project(':3rd:kiip')

    // MoPub SDK (Updated Jan 27, 2016)
    googleCompile project(':3rd:mopub-sdk')

    // Swrve SDK  (Updated Dec 7, 2015)
    //amazonCompile 'com.swrve.sdk.android:swrve:4.0.2'
    googleCompile 'com.swrve.sdk.android:swrve-google:4.4.0'

    // Compile the libs in the libs folder
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    compile files(
            'libs/fmodex.jar',
            'libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar' // (Updated Dec 8, 2015)
    )

    amazonCompile files('libs/in-app-purchasing-2.0.61.jar')

    googleCompile files('libs/KochavaSDK.jar') // (Updated Dec 8, 2015)
    googleCompile files('libs/tapjoy_mopub_v4.0.0.jar')
    googleCompile files('libs/tapjoy-android-fyber-4.0.0.jar')

    // Tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding multidexenabled true ?

Comment: yup, have been multidexing for a long time. You can see it in the error as the task is called app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForGoogleRelease

Comment: Then try cleaning the project and rebuild it once again.

Comment: yup, done that already

Comment: Are you using any google services ? Adding google play services in dependency may solve your problem

Comment: google play services

Comment: I don't know what's the problem actually, better give it a try http://stackoverflow.com/a/33690032/4608334

Comment: like this?:    googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2' // (Updated Aug 19, 2016)
    googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.2' // (Updated Aug 19, 2016)
    googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2' // (Updated Aug 19, 2016)
    googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.0.2' // (Updated Aug 19, 2016)
    //ad mob
    googleCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.0.2'
    googleCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'

Comment: Remove the unwanted libraries... Can you please edit the question and post the dependency block ?

Comment: all the listed libraries are needed, btw thx for all your replies

Comment: on the cli , use --info and or --debug to get more detail on the error in dex ....