# Errors after updating Firebase UI dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

After updating Firebase UI dependencies from `0.6.0` to `1.0.1`, the gradle build fails and shows following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

I am using `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1`. When I remove firebase-ads dependencies or go back to Firebase UI `0.6.0`, it works fine and builds gradle successfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)

Comment: but why it working fine with old dependencies

Comment: Older dependencies had smaller method count, thats why.

Comment: but after using multiDexEnabled true instant  run not working in pre-lollipop devices

Comment: Follow https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html to enable multidex even on pre-L devices.