# Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths

Tags: android, android-ndk

After updating my Android SDK suddenly i am getting the above error , any one facing this? i am using NDK also in my app which is working an hour back before upgrading Android studio and SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this post

[com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)

Adding this entry in build.gradle solved my problem.

defaultConfig {
 multiDexEnabled true
}