# getting this exception Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android

i am getting this exception in my app,I am trying to solve this for three days,what changes can remove this exception

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.class

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
compile(name:'lmrideviewlib', ext:'aar')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-core-2.3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-s3-2.3.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: What does `lmrideviewlib` do?

Comment: it's a sdk i am using in my app

Comment: I believe there's a dependency clash. Look for stuffs that is already being added by that sdk and then exclude it from your dependency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)