# Fail to install apk : Translation has been interrupted

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

Android Studio shows me the following error while install my app:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
```

I guess that maybe I have duplicate libraries.But I don't know which one is it.Can anybody tell how to get the duplicate library out?

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811133/3434561 and please provide more details.

Comment: Android Studio just shows the error above.So I am quite confused.

Comment: are you using any 9patch images or google play services?

Comment: Have you find any solution..?

Comment: @patelvatsal I add both maven library and local aar library in my project.Finally I find that jar of the same name exists in both maven library and aar, which results in a conflict.

Comment: @QianSijianhao Thank for your reply. I have the same issue. I had the same library used twice in the project.I removed one of them and now it's working.

Comment: @patelvatsal :)