# transformClassesWithMultidexlistForShopifyDebug?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex, shopify-app

Error:Execution failed for task ':sample:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForShopifyDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.multidex.ClassReferenceListBuilder with arguments {/project/bkup/13_feb_2018/valyangadi/sample/build/intermediates/multi-dex/shopify/debug/componentClasses.jar /project/bkup/13_feb_2018/valyangadi/sample/build/intermediates/transforms/jarMerging/shopify/debug/jars/1/1f/combined.jar}

We enabled  `multiDexEnabled true` and added 
    `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

```
 dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

and we try delete debug folder and clean ,rebuild 
but it still showing error

Comment: delete full build folder and try again

Comment: yes, i tried but no effect, the error showing again

Comment: if your gradle.properties contains org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M line then comment it and rebuild project

Comment: it was like this "org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxHeapSize\=2048m -Xmx2048m -XX\:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding\=UTF-8 -Dapollographql.skipRuntimeDep=true
" and now i commented it

Comment: please update the result after commenting it. is it work?

Comment: now it showing Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':sample'.

Comment: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':sample'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Comment: ok then revert it.. because some times error accured if there is too large heap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171679/discussion-between-learning-always-and-midhilaj).

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa